# How to build .apk file from Windows command-line?

Tags: android, apk

How can I build and signed (keystore) the .apk file using 'apkbuilder.bat' via windows command-line ?

I try to run the following line:

```
apkbuilder.bat %APK_File_Name% -u -z %Project_Path%\bin\resources.ap_ -f %Project_Path%\bin\classes.dex -rf %Project_Path%
```

but I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilderMain.main<ApkBuilderMain.java:61>
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to do this instead of just using eclipse?

Comment: @Falmarri Batch building, no?

Comment: commandline and builders project for my MBA

Comment: @Both of you: I know there are legitimate reasons. I just see a lot of questions here about compiling android projects because someone is reading a very old tutorial

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it in command line (.bat) in windows using ant.

with:
"ant release"
You build the apk unsigned.

Then you need to add the call to "jarsigner" and "zipalign" in the bat to complete the task.

You can find an example of the command line to call these tools here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#signapp

Best,

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using Ant and the build files generated by the Android tools rather than trying to handroll your own. If nothing else, you can use the build files as a reference to determine how it uses the various tools to perform each step.

Comment: This does not answer the question. There may be a good reason for not using the bundled ant scripts (such as working with an existing build system not based on ant).